# Order by with regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-order-by

there a column which i want to sort

```
C_NUMBER
---------
1718-SI-1
1718-SI-2
1718-SI-10
1718-SI-13
1718-SI-5
1718-SI-6
1718-SI-11
```

and this is the query where i am bringing my data in one table and applying order by but it is not working.

```
MYTABLE order by MYTABLE.C_NUMBER asc, patindex('%0-9]%',MYTABLE.C_NUMBER),len(MYTABLE.C_NUMBER)
```

Comment: view not supports order by follow this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/why-does-order-by-not-belong-in-a-view/

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to be ordering by the C_NUMBER first, just your patindex section. Try this;

```
order by patindex('%0-9]%',MYTABLE.C_NUMBER),len(MYTABLE.C_NUMBER)
```

Comment: i m getting this error while executing this in my view The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @abhishek I see. If you are creating a view with an order by statement, you must add top 100 percent (or whatever you need). Try that.

Comment: @JPF While that might allow the view to be created, it will not have the intended effect. A view, like a table, has no particular order. If rows in a resultset require order, then the query that generates that resultset **must** include the appropriate order by clause.

Comment: @SMor you can include an 'order' statement in a view so your statement is incorrect

Comment: @JPF No one said you couldn't include one - but it has no effect if it is used with "top 100 percent". The optimizer is smart enough to see past this pointless usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;With cte(C_NUMBER)
AS
(
SELECT '1718-SI-1'   UNION ALL
SELECT '1718-SI-2'  UNION ALL
SELECT '1718-SI-10' UNION ALL
SELECT '1718-SI-13' UNION ALL
SELECT '1718-SI-5'  UNION ALL
SELECT '1718-SI-6'  UNION ALL
SELECT '1718-SI-11'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
Order by  CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(C_NUMBER),0, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(C_NUMBER)))) AS INT)
```

Result

```
C_NUMBER
----------
1718-SI-1
1718-SI-2
1718-SI-5
1718-SI-6
1718-SI-10
1718-SI-11
1718-SI-13
```

Comment: but patindex in your query returns position of the last integer value ,not possible to sort with that query

Answer (score 0):

This code will cut your string in three parts and use these values - **typesafe!!** - in the `ORDER BY` clause separately. This will sort differen `1718-SI` or `1719-BI` or whatever you might have.

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, C_NUMBER VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('1718-SI-1')
,('1718-SI-2')
,('1718-SI-10')
,('1718-SI-13')
,('1718-SI-5')
,('1718-SI-6')
,('1718-SI-11');

SELECT * FROM @mockup;

SELECT m.*
FROM @mockup AS m
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(m.C_NUMBER,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Parted(AsXML)
ORDER BY AsXML.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','int')
        ,AsXML.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
        ,AsXML.value('/x[3]/text()[1]','int')
```

### HINT: Your design breaks **1.NF**

Store the three parts in three different typed columns, apply indexes and create the output format *on-the-fly*. You should not store more than one value in a cell...